# CMake one build directory for multiple projects

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I´m a beginner user of CMake. My environment has several projects like:

```
project
  |------ CMakeLists.txt (The main Cmake)
  |------ ProjectA
  |          |----- .cpp files
  |          |----- .hpp files
  |          |----- CMakeList.txt
  |------ ProjectB
  |          |----- .cpp files
  |          |----- .hpp files
  |          |----- CMakeList.txt
  | 
  |------ build
  |         |-----  CMakeStuff
  |------ bin
  |        |---- executables
  |------ lib
  |        |---- libwhatever.a
  |------ db 
           |---- Database stuff
```

I would like to use a single build directory for every project, as showed above. Preferrably that It can be divided into multiple subprojects, like `build/projectA`, `build/ProjectB` so that if I need to rebuild a single project I can delete the whole `build/Project` file and all is gone and a new `Cmake` will build it again.

I´m having difficulties configuring CMAKE.

My original CMakeList.txt on the project folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2.)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../bin)

project(projectA)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")

add_library(commonmessage SHARED ${SOURCES})

install(TARGETS commonmessage DESTINATION ../lib)
```

My questions are:

A) What will happen if I run cmake on a single build directory - is that possible and what would be the correct CMAKE configuration ?

B) My compilation for `ProjectA` needs to include files from `ProjectB` - how can I set that in the `CMakeLists.txt` for each individual project ?

C) At the end I need a single makefile to build all, as well as the option to build each project individually. Will that be possible with a single build directory ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't look like the CMake code you posted belongs to the top CMakeList.txt file, since it directly references .cpp files, and "projectA".
There are also a few things that are not idiomatic:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2.)
```

why the trailing dot here ? Not sure whether cmake will complain, but it is useless either way.

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

Don't do that. Instead invoke cmake using the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` command line flag, or use ccmake, or a GUI, or edit the CMakeCache.txt file.

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")
```

Don't do that either. It is good practice to explicitely list source files in CMake, because globbing will not make cmake detect newly added or deleted files automatically. Some people might disagree though.

Now for the heart of the topic, here is how things are usually done:

Top CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
project(globalProject)

add_subdirectory(projectA)
add_subdirectory(projectB)
```

ProjectA CMakeLists.txt file (assuming projectA is an executable):

```
add_executable(projectA file1.cpp file2.cpp ... )
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/projectB) # include files from ProjectB
target_link_libraries(projectA projectB)

install(TARGETS projectA RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

ProjectB CMakeLists.txt file (assuming projectB is a library):

```
add_library(projectB file1.cpp file2.cpp ... )

install(TARGETS projectB
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

Please note that this setup needs the `make install` step to create bin and lib at the location of your choice as given in the command line invocation of cmake `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=..` (assuming make is run from the build dir).

Also, this setup lets you choose if you want to build static or shared libraries, by using: `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`. To build both, you need to have two `add_library` calls with two different names, one STATIC, the other SHARED.

To sum up the steps required to make this work:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=.. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
$ make
$ make install
```

You could put these commands in a script for reusability.

Now, your questions can be answered:

A) it is possible and recommended, see the code above, only one build directory is necessary.

B) See the code for the projectA/CMakeLists.txt, you have to call `include_directories()`

C) Yes it is possible. Each target in your project can be built individually from the build directory by using make and the target name: `make projectB` and `make projectA`

Comment: Sir, thanks for help... what if I need to generate the lib and bin files in the target foldert without needing to `make install` ?

Comment: While it is possible by using the `CMAKE_*_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variables, I wouldn't recommend doing this, because you may have several build directories with several configurations (Debug vs. Release, different compiler, etc) and it is always good to be able to test them in parallel without overwriting files when compiling. Why do you need bin/lib at the root of your project ?

Comment: Good point. `bin` is where all executables will be installed. `lib´ will hold all libraries.

Comment: `install (TARGETS projectA, projectB...` is issuing `install TARGETS given target "projectA" which does not exist in this   directory`... Not working because of the subdirectory

Comment: Does it work if you put one `install` call in each of the two specific CMakeLists.txt files right after declaring the target ?

Comment: No. It seens not to recognize subdirectories: [Check here](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14444)

Comment: well then, like I just said, put the install directives in each subdirectory :)

Comment: Hm, I also have this Setup. But I wonder whether it is the best way if you use docker. Because docker can cache steps but here we have one call to build that does everything

Answer (score 3):

A) You can do 1 CMakeLists.txt for N projects. When you define a library, you can use it in an executable defined in the cmake (add_executable and  target_link_libraries to see).

B) see target_include_directories

C) it seems you can call `cmake --target target` to generate the Makefile for only one of the target of your cmakelists.txt file.